# How to get variables from MSQL query with WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a couple of MySQL tables where I run a query on like this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT my_item 
  FROM t1
     , t2 
 WHERE t1.id='$id' 
   AND t2.spec IN (208, 606, 645) 
   AND t1.spec = t2.spec
";
```

Note I am using the WHERE IN.

Next I run a query and use WHILE to try to get the results:

```
$retval = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$myitem = $row['my_item'];
echo "My item is $myitem<br />\n";
}
```

This prints three results, each with a different value for $myitem, based on the three options from the IN clause in the SELECT statement at the beginning.

How can I extract and store each of these three values in a separate variable each?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if  $myitem was an array, and then the 'variables' are simply the elements of the array?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, Strawberry! To do that, should I use $myitem = array($row['my_item']); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `join`

```
SELECT my_item FROM t1 join t2 
on t1.spec=t2.spec
WHERE t1.id='$id' 
AND t2.spec IN (208, 606, 645)
```

or create array

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$myitem[] = $row['my_item'];
}
```

use this array likt that :-

```
foreach( $myitem as  $myitems){
echo "My item is $myitems<br />\n";
}
```

or use indexing

```
echo "My item is $myitems[0]";
```

Comment: Will give this a try, Rahautos! My problem, though, is extracting the 3 results in individual PHP variables from the while loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rahautos, it woks like a charm!

Comment: it's my pleasure :) - @Cucurigu

Comment: if my answer helps you please accept my answer @Cucurigu

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `$row['my_item']` in an array. 
Refer [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)